# Change PostgreSQL data_directory on CentOS 7

Tags: postgresql, centos, centos7, datadirectory

I'm trying to change the default data_directory of PostgreSQL on CentOS 7 however without much success. I've an experience of successful change on Ubuntu, using the following manual:

http://climber2002.github.io/blog/2015/02/07/install-and-configure-postgresql-on-ubuntu-14-dot-04/

However I'm not able to do that on CentOS, the directories are different, can't find how to call initdb to create the new cluster, move the existing DB files to the new directory, etc.

Can anybody advise on this? Didn't find anything useful on this either.

Thanks.

Comment: Stop the server, move the cluster and create a symlink in the old place.

Comment: Thanks, but symlink won't work, I want the DB files to be stored on an SSD, creating symlink will write the files in both places, that's not what I'm up to.

Comment: What?? A symlink will point to the cluster. I don't get what you mean by _will write the files in both places_

Comment: Thank you, however there should be a more elegant way of doing so, like in the link I've given in my original question.

Comment: In that page a new cluster is created in another directory but all the data remains in the old cluster and will have to be moved by other means. Isn't there data already?

Comment: Moving is not the problem. The problem is to permanently change the data_directory.

Comment: Did you try the steps in your link? I think, it's /usr/lib/pgsql on Red Hat like systems, and /usr/lib/postgresql on Debian like systems.

Comment: Unfortunately none of those paths exist. Those instructions from the page I gave work just fine for Ubuntu, but not for CentOS.

Comment: You can see it on the output of `ps x` (as postgres) It is "hardcoded" in the startup script (/etc/init.d/postgresql) and in the data-directory, also for the logfile(s). The symlink-trick is a nice hack to avoid editing of the config file(s)